# What should I add to my modal to show up?

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-5

I have the following html file, and the modal won't show up. Do I have to add something here, or to somewhere else? Do I have to write a button onclick function as well? It should show up when "delete" button being pressed.

```
<div class="card-group"  *ngIf="view == true">
      <div>
        <button (click)="changeView()">List view</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let driver of drivers" >
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ driver.name}}</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{ driver.team}}</h6>
        <button (click)="updateDriver(driver.id)" class="btn btn-outline-info">
          Update
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" style="margin-left: 10px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
          Delete
        </button>
        <button (click)="driverDetails(driver.id)" class="btn btn-outline-info" style="margin-left: 10px">
          Details
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" *ngFor="let driver of drivers" >
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button (click)="deleteDriver(driver.id)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Small changes would be required.

`*ngFor="let driver of drivers"` would create multiple div with same id `exampleModal`. Id's need to be unique.

Try removing the loop or give unique each id each time and then use that id in the delete button `data-target=""` attribute.

Based on the requirement, you should consider using a `BehaviorSubject`.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject

1. Create a component which will hold the modal html.
2. Create a service with behaviour subject.
3. Inject the service in modal component and your component.
4. Your component would pass the values of driver to through behaviour subject using `.next()` method
5. The newly created modal component would subscribe to the behaviour subject variable and will get the new values passed from the component. Then you can populate the modal html accordingly.
6. When the user click 'Confirm Delete', you would change the values & pass it to your initial component and perform a delete api call.

Comment: But if I remove the loop, then it wouldn't show all the drivers from the list, would it?

Comment: In that case add the index of the loop to the id and use it in the data-target

Comment: drivers data is populated inside the popup body? or you wanted to duplicate each driver detail as a separate div with id exampleModal?

Comment: Driver data shouldn't show up in the modal. I have a site, and there are drivers, and each has a delete button next to their name. The only purpose is when that button clicked, a popup windows should appear. I haven't used modal before, I saw this implementation on the documentation. However I'm still not sure how should I do this. How should the modal div know the id of the driver?

Comment: Updated my answer with the approach which will be ideal for your use case

Comment: I think the problem is something else, because if I replace my modal button outside of the loop, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz link with minimal code to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing data-target and data-toggle in the below code to data-bs-target and data-bs-toggle respectively.

```html
<button
    class="btn btn-outline-danger"
    style="margin-left: 10px"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#exampleModal">Delete</button>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).